# Error Function Scene Adobe Animate Syntax Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i tried to use adobe animate 2019 to make a quiz. there are some errors:

- Scene 15, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 68, Column 7    1083: Syntax
  error: else is unexpected.

  - Scene 15, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 63, Column 47 1084: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before rightparen. Scene 15, Layer
    'Actions', Frame 1, Line 62, Column 53   1084: Syntax error: expecting
    identifier before logicaland.

Here's my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//melakukan inisialisasi posisi awal dari object
//fungsi ini dibuat terutama untuk keperluan "me-reset posisi object"
function inisialisasi_posisi():void{ //
      benar_mc.visible = false;
      salah_mc.visible = false;

    //posisi ayah
    ayah_mc.x = posisiawal_ayah_mc.x;
    ayah_mc.y = posisiawal_ayah_mc.y;

    //posisi kakak
    kakak_mc.x = posisiawal_kakak_mc.x;
    kakak_mc.y = posisiawal_kakak_mc.y;

    //posisi ibu
    ibu_mc.x = posisiawal_ibu_mc.x;
    ibu_mc.y = posisiawal_ibu_mc.y;

    //posisi adik
    adik_mc.x = posisiawal_adik_mc.x;
    adik_mc.y = posisiawal_adik_mc.y;

} //

inisialisasi_posisi();

//DRAG & DROP OBJECT
function dragdrop(object_mc:MovieClip):void
{
      object_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startdrag);
      object_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdrag);
}

function startdrag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
      e.currentTarget.startDrag();
}
function stopdrag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
      e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}

//set dragdrop
dragdrop(ayah_mc);
dragdrop(kakak_mc);
dragdrop(ibu_mc);
dragdrop(adik_mc);

//result
test_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test);

function test(e:MouseEvent):void
{
      //jika semua object berada pada tempat yang benar
      if(ayah_mc.hitTestObject(ayahTarget_mc)== true &&
         kakak_mc.hitTestObject(kakakTarget_mc)== true &&
         ibu_mc.hitTestObject(ibuTarget_mc)== true) &&
         adik_mc.hitTestObject(adikTarget_mc)== true) ;
      {
            benar_mc.visible = true;
            salah_mc.visible = false;
      }
      else
      {
            benar_mc.visible = false;
            salah_mc.visible = true;
      }
}

//reset object ke posisi awal
reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);

function reset(e:MouseEvent):void
{
      inisialisasi_posisi();
}

/* Click to Go to Scene and Play
Clicking on the specified symbol instance plays the movie from the specified scene and frame.

Instructions:
1. Replace "Scene 3" with the name of the scene you would like play.
2. Replace 1 with the frame number you would like the movie to play from in the specified scene.
*/

button_nextquiz1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_16);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_16(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 16");
}

/* Click to Go to Previous Scene and Play
Clicking on the specified symbol instance moves the playhead to the previous scene in the timeline and continues playback in that scene.
*/

button_previousquiz1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToPreviousScene_17);

function fl_ClickToGoToPreviousScene_17(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).prevScene();
}

stop();
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: There is a semicolon **;** right after the huge **if (...)**  block. Remove it.

Comment: i removed the semicolon but still have the same problems.
- Scene 15, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 65, Column 7 1083: Syntax error: else is unexpected.
- Scene 15, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 60, Column 53 1084: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before rightparen.
- Scene 15, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 59, Column 53 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before logicaland.

Comment: When you do some changes to your code, please edit your question to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parentheses and and extra semicolon in the `if` condition inside your `test` function. Change it to:

```
function test(e:MouseEvent):void
{
      //jika semua object berada pada tempat yang benar
      if(ayah_mc.hitTestObject(ayahTarget_mc) == true &&
         kakak_mc.hitTestObject(kakakTarget_mc) == true &&
         ibu_mc.hitTestObject(ibuTarget_mc) == true &&
         adik_mc.hitTestObject(adikTarget_mc) == true)
      {
            benar_mc.visible = true;
            salah_mc.visible = false;
      }
      else
      {
            benar_mc.visible = false;
            salah_mc.visible = true;
      }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question, but i got new error: 
Scene 15, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 22, Column 17 1120: Access of undefined property posisiawal_adik_mc.

and this error
Scene 15, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 23, Column 17 1120: Access of undefined property posisiawal_adik_mc.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to reference a movieclip that is not there. Check the stage on frame 1 and see if a movieclip with the instance name of `posisiawal_adik_mc` is there.